# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in quick sort algorithm

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, quicksort

Below is my code for Quick sort i C. I am getting Segmentation fault Core Dumped.
I tried hard to resolve the issue but found nothing.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int divide(int a[], int p, int q) {
    int mid, i, lastsmall, temp;

    mid = (p + q)/2;
    temp = a[mid];
    a[mid] = a[p];
    a[p] = temp;
    int pivot = a[p];
    lastsmall = p;

    for (i = p + 1; i <= q; i++) {
        if (a[p] > pivot)
            continue;
        else {
             lastsmall++;
             temp = a[i];
             a[i] = lastsmall;
             lastsmall = a[i];
        }
    }
    return lastsmall;
}

void quick(int a[], int p, int q) {
    int pivot;
    if (p < q) {
        pivot = divide(a, p, q);
        quick(a, p, pivot);
        quick(a, pivot + 1, q);
    }
}

int main() {
    int ar[10], i;

    printf("Enter the list\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10;i++)
        scanf("%d", &ar[i]);
    quick(ar, 0, 9);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d ", ar[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I tried hard to resolve the issue but found nothing.". So what did you find out? At a very very minimum you should be able to tell us which line of code is causing the seg fault. A debugger will give you that info (and more).

Comment: Even w/o debugger, did you try to read your code and understand what do you actually do in each its row?

Comment: `a[i] = lastsmall;
             lastsmall = a[i];` ?? and `if(a[p]>pivot)
            continue;` ??

Answer (score -1):

**EDITED** to add some explanations

The segfault was easy to pinpoint in line 26, an off-by-one. I couldn't make sense of your `divide` function, so I just implemented the search for the pivot after the pseudocode at [Rosetta](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort). Found that simple and easy to understand.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int divide(int a[], int low, int high)
{
  int pivot, tmp;

  // Yes, you can choose other start values.
  pivot = (low + high)/2;

  while (low <= high) {
    while (a[low] < a[pivot]) {
      low++;
    }
    while (a[high] > a[pivot]) {
      high--;
    }
    if (low <= high) {
      tmp = a[low];
      a[low] = a[high];
      a[high] = tmp;
      low++;
      high--;
    }
  }
  return pivot;
}

void quick(int a[], int p, int q)
{
  int pivot;
  if (p < q) {
    pivot = divide(a, p, q);
    // Here was your segfault
    quick(a, p, pivot - 1);
    quick(a, pivot + 1, q);
  }
}

int main()
{
  int ar[10], i;
  printf("Enter the list\n");
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &ar[i]);
  }
  quick(ar, 0, 9);
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%d ", ar[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

A real implementation would involve a lot of pointer-juggling, a function to compare the elements, passed as a function pointer, and a large heap of optimizations. See for example the [GLibC implementation](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/qsort.c).

The **EDIT** promised above:

The pivot itself can by anything as long as it is somewhere in the input, it can even be constant, as I had before. Many papers have been written about the choice of the pivot and the only thing they all have in common is the conclusion: it depends on the expected input.

I have put a counter in the outer `while` loop (prob. better to count the number of compares) and generated 100 random integers between 10 and 10,000 a hundred times. The average number of "rounds" was for returning

- `low` = 168.55
- `--low` = 185.67
- `high` = inf (obviously)
- `++high` = 174.87
- `pivot` = 216.04 (that is: always the start index which increments by one every second call)

If I change the pivot to be the floor of the geometric mean I get

- `low` = 153.22
- `--low` = 152.65
- `high` = inf
- `++high` = 151.88
- `pivot` = 134.85

Counting the actual number of compares and with an array of 100,000 elements of random integers between 10 and 1,000,000 (pivot is still the geometric mean), averaged compares of hundred runs

- `low` = 12762491.95
- `--low` = 12756154.17
- `high` = inf
- `++high` = 12702092.52
- `pivot` = 13121675.81

The same with pivot set to geometric mean

- `low` = 12749755.60
- `--low` = 12801865.60
- `high` = inf
- `++high` = 12705592.10
- `pivot` = 13113604.20

Some might say that the number of calls to `quick()` (calls to `divide()` are a bit more than half of that with a constant factor) would be a better measurement and they are also right. Only 10 rounds this time.

Same

- `low` = 1281068.00
- `--low` = 1225781.20
- `high` = inf
- `++high` = 1221477.00
- `pivot` = 1048575.00

Same, input sorted low to high

- `low` = 1280983.80
- `--low` = 1225749.80
- `high` = inf
- `++high` = 1221376.80
- `pivot` = 1048575.00

Same, input sorted high to low

- `low` = 1281025.80
- `--low` = 1225738.80
- `high` = inf
- `++high` = 1221632.20
- `pivot` = 1048575.00

Test with the `divide()` proposed by WhozCraig:

Unsorted input: 1333671.00
Sorted input (low to high): 1333513.60
Sorted input (high to low): 1333594.80

Stable runtimes but also a small but significant bit slower (for the given input!).

Conclusion: for an uniformly distributed, random, dense input set, setting the pivot to the geometric mean between `low` and `high` seems to save the most comparisons. Returning the start pivot or one of the more optimal values computed later differs by a significant but quite small factor in comparisons but a rather large one in actual calls to `quick()`.

This *will* differ for other input sets and other pivot values (you can also use several pivots), and also for different architectures.

It is indeed possible to waste a lot of time in optimizing quicksort, so be cautious!

Comment: @WhozCraig Yepp, that's a typo (prob. from C&P 'ing a single function into the two functions the OP made). What held you back from repairing this obvious blunder?